# HttpParseException in scaffolding-generated view code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I get the following exception with the following code in ASP.NET MVC5. I used the built-in scaffolding to generate my view code (List), and it just doesn't work. The exception is about an else block, but it is thrown at the second  element in my **foreach** so I have absolutely no idea what is going on (here: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nem)`).

I read about this exception but that cases were really about an if-else case so I can't use that solutions and still don't know what I have done wrong.

> **System.Web.HttpParseException**: 'The else block is missing a closing
>   "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all
>   the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}"
>   characters are being interpreted as markup.'

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nem)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SzuletesiIdo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SzuletesiHely)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Taj)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Irsz)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telepules)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cim)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mobil)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OtthoniTel)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnyaNev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnyaMobil)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnyaEmail)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApaNev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApaMobil)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApaEmail)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TanfolyamSorszam)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TanfolyamOsztaly)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Csoport)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BallagasEv)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KimaradtDatum)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PoloMeret)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Iskola)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BkkIgazolvany)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MavIgazolvany)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MakIgazolvany)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProgramUtanHaza)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EgeszsegugyiTudnivalo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Egyeb)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.GyerekId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.GyerekId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.GyerekId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**EDIT**: item.Nem is an enum type (with two possible values). I use a DisplayTemplate for displaying enums (Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Enum.cshtml):

```
@model Enum

@if (EnumHelper.IsValidForEnumHelper(ViewData.ModelMetadata))
{
    // Display Enum using same names (from [Display] attributes) as in editors
    string displayName = null;
    foreach (SelectListItem item in EnumHelper.GetSelectList(ViewData.ModelMetadata, (Enum)Model))
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            displayName = item.Text ?? item.Value;
        }
    }

    // Handle the unexpected case that nothing is selected
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
    {
        if (Model == null)
        {
            displayName = String.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            displayName = Model.ToString();
        }
    }

    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => displayName)
}
else
{
    // This Enum type is not supported.  Fall back to the text.
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model)
```

Comment: Do you mind to show us the `Model` so we can see what the `Nem` property looks like?

Comment: @Svek I edited the post. 'Nem' property is an enum type, you can read in the editted post how I display enums.

Comment: Where is the closing `}` at the end of your second code block? Sort of looks like the problem that the thrown exception is pointing at!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your second code block *(Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Enum.cshtml)*:

> You are missing the closing `}` at the end of your `else` statement

Which is exactly what the exception is telling you :)